# Why my UV unwrap is messed up after joining all objects

Tags: mesh, uv, baking, uv-image-editor

My turret model is made up of a lot of separate meshes and I UV unwrapped them separately as well, each of their UV map is fine w/ acceptable stretching but after I join all objects together, then unwrap the whole object, some parts which have fine UV maps before became heavily stretched. What should I do to fix this?

[image]
Independent objects before joining them

[image]
After joining objects and unwrapping

Comment: why unwrapping again after joining? If you don't it will keep the original UV. Since you joined the different parts, unwrapping tries to optimize the combined meshes.

Comment: The heavy stretching of the highlighted part of my model still exist even I did not unwrap the whole object again after joining all meshes.

Comment: Only certain parts of joined mesh are selected hence it's unclear what was reunwrapped and how it was done (since selected islands intersect with other ones). Ngons will nearly always behave unpredictable when unwrapping (and not only), consider converting them to quads/tris. Check that scale is applied for both objects which are being joined.

Comment: Triangulating the stretched meshes worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: did you try to select the object then "pack islands" ? it should keep everything the way it is, and change only the size to make the islands fit